# What is 'int border = borderType & ~BORDER_ISOLATED' variable means?

Tags: c++

I'm  trying too figure out what to define the meaning of this variable in opencv. As i know, `BORDER_ISOLATED` or `BORDER_DEFAULT` is a `#define` variable in opencv. I try to make example like this to describe:

```
int borderType = BORDER_DEFAULT;
int borderIsolated = borderType & BORDER_ISOLATED;
int borderIsolatedDest = borderType & ~BORDER_ISOLATED;
```

What is "`borderType & BORDER_ISOLATED`" means? And what's the differences between with and without tilde? Is it a Destructor?

Thank you

Comment: Read a textbook, SO is not a replacement for that - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: @OP -- Frameworks and libraries such as `opencv` assume you already know at least the basics of the language you will be using.  They are not to be used as language tutorials.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry i just confused about this variable on Opencv. So what should i do? delete the tags or change the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is **bitwise AND**, which means performing the logical AND operation on each pair of the corresponding bits. For example:
`5 & 3 = 1`, that is `0101 & 0011 = 0001`
`~` is **bitwise NOT**, which means performing logical negation on each bit. For example: 
`~7 = 8`, that is `~0111 = 1000`

> Note: I don't consider two's complement in the above examples.

Comment: Ok i get it now. Thanks!